# How to switch between two or mutlple chrome browser windows (Not tabs) using selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is code that I want to do switching. I do some stuff at user X and then again by calling openbrowser() method I login to user y and do some stuff now want to switch to X user chrome browser again for next actions.

```java
public static void openbrowser() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
    
    
public static void navigateAppUrl(int row, int column) throws Exception {
    driver.get(excel.readData(row , column));
}
    
public static void LogintoXUser() {
    //Do some stuff//
}
    
public static void LogintoYUser() {
    //Do some stuff//
}
    
public static void main(String args[]){
    openbrowser();
    navigateAppUrl(1,2);
    LogintoXUser()
    
    // new chrome browser instance is created 
    openbrowser();
    navigateAppUrl(1,2);
    LogintoYUser()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change method `openbrowser()` to `WebDriver`. You can create more instances of WebDriver and arbitrarily use them.

```
public static WebDriver openbrowser() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        WebDriver driver1 = openbrowser();
        // do some staff with driver1
        
        WebDriver driver2 = openbrowser();
        // do some staff with driver2

       // continue with some staff with driver1
       driver1....

       // continue with some staff with driver2
       driver2....

    }
```